# Adding custom attributes to the SiteMap of ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, web.sitemap

I am using built in asp.net sitemap in asp.net mvc with the following schema

> http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0

I have the following attributes, resourcekey, title & description. I would like to add few more attributes to the sitemapNode, kindly let me know if it is possible to add new attribute in sitemap file and then read it via the sitemap class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The SiteMap schema supports custom attributes and they can be accessed via the indexer property of the `SiteMapNode` class.

For example if the following node was defined in the Web.sitemap file with custom tooltip attribute:

```
<siteMapNode url="~/Default.aspx" title="Home" tooltip="My Home Page" />
```

It can then be accessed via the SiteMapNode indexer e.g.

```
string tooltip = siteMapNodeInstance["tooltip"];
```

More information on customising SiteMaps is available [here](http://ianoxley.wordpress.com/2008/06/07/adding-custom-attributes-to-aspnet-site-map-files-to-improve-accessibility/)